# Django Register Form redirecting to same url

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

i am new to django i have created a user registration form but when i click on submit it does nothing and just goes to the same page i am not under standing what i did wrong here
views.py:

```
class RegisterPage(FormView):
    template_name = "main/register.html"
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        if user is not None:
            login(self.request, user)
        return super(RegisterPage, self).form_valid(form)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect("blog_list")
        return super(RegisterPage, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    bio = forms.CharField(max_length=400, empty_value="Max Length 400")
    image = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "image", "password1", "password2", "bio"]
```

register.html:

```
{% extends "main/main.html" %}

{% block title %}Create an Account{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="form">
    <h1>Register</h1>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label>{{form.username.label}}</label>
            {{form.username}}
            <br>
            <label>{{form.password1.label}}</label>
            {{form.password1}}
            <br>
            <label>{{form.password2.label}}</label>
            {{form.password2}}
            <br>
            <label>{{form.image.label}}</label>
            {{form.image}}
            <br>
            <label>{{form.bio.label}}</label>
            {{form.bio}}
            <br>
            <input style="margin-top: 10px" class="button" type="submit" value="Register"/>
        </form>
        <p>Already Have An Account <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="button">Login</a></p>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

in the views.py i have also tried form_class = UserCreationForm the built in django creation form but still the same result so what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're posting the form back but you've only implemented a get method:

```
 def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect("blog_list")
        return super(RegisterPage, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

And on the form html you're saying use POST `<form method="post">` which is correct, and is the prefered way to send information you don't want to be sent in the URL. For example if you used `<form method="get">` you code might work, but you'd also be sending the contents of the form in the url. Post sends it in the body, so if you use https on your server only you and the browser see it.

TO MAKE POST work you need to (add)

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
       #check the form do the redirect
```

As you didn't have an action on the form it defaults to submitting to the current url.

You need both get and post, as get will load the form post is how you're sending it back.

Comment: it didnt work could you explain where to put the post method i replaced the get with post but aint working

Comment: I didn't sey replace the get method, I said add the post method (as well as your get)

Comment: @MoeezAli I've added a little more detail for you, hope that clears things up.